# MVC4 How to go about using IsInRole without SimpleMemberShip

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just curious what would be the best way to do this?

used to using

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```

with an older program of mine,

Using the new Kendo templete( new to me ) for MVC4-VS2012 Projects it created everything w/o simplemembership, so i wrote my own login system with help of some youtube videos and documentations.

It is very flexible and works, just curious on how I can check if a user is in a Roll Via A view ( like `if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))` ) would have done. And or the best way to do so ( possibly in controller )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue to use `User.IsInRole("")`, you simply need to set `HttpContext.User` with the correct principal that has a list of roles.

You can create your own Authorization Attribute that would take care of this:

```
var websiteRoles = userRepo.GetRoles(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

var identity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity as FormsIdentity;
filterContext.HttpContext.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(identity, websiteRoles.ToArray());
```

**Follow up:**

Your GetRoles() method can be implemented any way you like, you simply need to have a list of roles that the user belongs to. You will use this list to create the Principal object to set the User to.

Using this approach will allow you to use User.IsInRole()

Comment: I'm sorry new to this ... Where exactly do i Set that by the IsInRole method? - Also does this intell that i have to use a many to many - User to Roles table in my database? - for my tables i currently have a user table with a inRole Column ( so its all in 1 table )

Comment: ok so this is done in my dbContext Class File then ? - awesome thanks!

Comment: okay so for some reason I cannot get this to stick in my Context Class, where am i to place this code?

Comment: UserRepo, FormIdentity filterContext(wich is prob my context) does not exists in current context, ideas? -

Comment: The `userRepo` was just an example of calling the repository class that would take care of member-related database calls. 

The `filterContext` field name comes from: `public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)` that is in my custom Authorization Attribute. Are you creating your own authorization attribute or are you doing this inside of a base controller, or somewhere else?

Comment: I'd like to create my own authorization attribute with your code provided. I have been looking at how to impliment this but no where can i find the correct spot to implement these. It may just be that i do not understand enough about `Custom Authorization Attributes` and or how it will work with filtercontext and userRepo... I'd have to view the full sourcecode of something like this to understand, or a close to complete example. ( I was creating a new `Folder "Filter"` and stuck all the code in a Class called `AuthUsr`, but further then that .. unsure ow to create `UserRepo` andFilterContext.

Comment: I'm sorry guess thats really unrelated and not your issue, but if you felt like helping me getting started in the right direction i'd appreciate it. thanks for your help so far